# How do I test Go's "testing" package functions?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

I'm writing a library of testing utility functions and I would like them to be themselves tested.

An example of one such function is:

```
func IsShwifty(t *testing.T, foo string) bool {
    result, err := bar.MyFunction(string)
    if err != nil {
      t.Error("Failed to get shwifty: " + foo, err)
    }
    return result == "shwifty"
}
```

I would like to write a `TestIsShwifty` that feeds in something to make `MyFunction` return an error and then make `t.Error`. Then, I want to have the `TestIsShwifty` pass with something like:

```
func TestIsShwifty(t *testing.T) {
  if doesError(t, IsShwifty(t)) == false {
    t.Error("Oh know! We didn't error!")
  }
}
```

Is this possible in Go?

Comment: What are the obstacles you came across? What is the error?

Comment: The error will break my test, but I would like my test to pass when it errors.

Comment: It seems you want something that is not supported by the test tool. I don't think you are going to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

I just needed to create a separate instance of `testing.T`.

```
func TestIsShwifty(t *testing.T) {
  newT := testing.T{}
  IsShwifty(newT)
  if newT.Failed() == false {
    t.Error("Test should have failed")
  }
}
```